# Reading FIFO in LSM6DS3

Tags: sensor, accelerometer, mems, gyroscope

What is the difference between reading the FIFO registers(FIFO_DATA_OUT_L,FIFO_DATA_OUT_H) and Sensor output registers(OUTX_L_XL to OUTZ_H_XL) both are same?which is recommended to get the raw data from the sensor

Answer (score 1):

Reading the sensor output registers (OUTX_L_XL .. OUTZ_H_XL) gives you the most recent sensor readings. Reading the FIFO can give you data that occurred in the past. By using the FIFO, you can set up the chip to automatically sample and store data in the FIFO, at the rate you want (e.g. 52 Hz, 104 Hz, 208 Hz, ...) and you don't need to bother your MCU to continuously poll the LSM6DS3. Only at some point you may bulk-transfer all samples to your MCU. This saves CPU time and possibly power. Both are viable methods of reading the LSM6DS3 - depends on your application.

If your MCU does other tasks besides polling the LSM6DS3, it may be better to use the FIFO method, as it ensures you won't miss any data and your MCU will be less involved in communication with the LSM6DS3.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.When FIFO_CTRL5 register will comes into picture?
1)If I use Output registers(X,Y,Z) to read the data what are all the settings required?
2)If I use FIFO output registers to read the data what will be the settings and what is the recommended FIFO ODR value if the ODR(Accelerometer only) is 104Hz.

Comment: 1) You can take a look in the [LSM6 Arduino library](https://github.com/pololu/lsm6-arduino) as a good, working reference on how to set up the device; 2) You'll probably want to use the same ODR for both the accelerometer (CTRL1_XL) and the FIFO (FIFO_CTRL5).

Comment: Please clarify wether reading the data is proper or not 
Generating the interrupt for every 1sec on FTH(Accelerometer ODR 104Hz and FIFO ODR 104Hz).means in 1 sec I will get 312samples(X 104samples Y 104samples and Z 104samples).
If I read all 309 samples (since it is not recommended to read the full data,so leaving one set of data) how many bytes will store in FIFO_DATA_OUT_L and how many in 
FIFO_DATA_OUT_H.[Contd..]

Comment: [Contd..]If I want to get 1st X sample do I need to read the first byte of FIFO_DATA_OUT_L and first byte of FIFO_DATA_OUT_H and combining them after shifting MSB ?If not how can I get raw XYZ data by reading these registers
FIFO_DATA_OUT_L and FIFO_DATA_OUT_H.Please do update me with an example

Comment: Reading the FIFO is as simple as reading FIFO_DATA_OUT_L, then FIFO_DATA_OUT_H - this gives you one complete word when you combine them. You keep reading this way until you get the number of words needed. E.g. for accelerometer ODR 104, without gyro, this means 104 * 3 words per second.

Comment: Hi some problem in reading the data from FIFO.
Using only Accelerometer.Accelerometer ODR is 104 Hz and FIFO ODR is 104Hz still not getting the proper data these are my settings.
Please update me if anything is needs to be updated / modified.
CTRL1_XL 0x40 //104Hz,2g 
CTRL9_XL 0x38 //To get proper data X,Y,Z 
CTRL3_C 0x64 //BDU=1,H_LACTIVE=1,IF_INC=1 
CTRL4_C 0x01 //STOP ON FTH 
FIFO_CTRL1 0x9C //156samples X 52 samples ,Y 52samples,Z 52 samples 
FIFO_CTRL2 0x00 
FIFO_CTRL3 0x01 //No decimation 
FIFO_CTRL5 0x26 //Mode Continuous and FIFO ODR 104Hz..[Contd.....]

Comment: [Contd...]When ever Interrupt comes am reading 153 samples from FIFO_DATA_OUT_L and 153 from FIFO_DATA_OUT_H register[Contd..] 

[Contd..] If I take first byte from FIFO_DATA_OUT_L and first byte from FIFO_DATA_OUT_H after combining and shifting it should give X value similarly for all X Y and Z.
Am doing the following the same approach still am not getting the proper data,where as if I read through out registers(OUTX_L_XL ..OUTZ_H_XL) the data is correct. 
Is there anymore settings need to get the proper FIFO data or am I doing anything wrong in reading the FIFO. please help me out.

Comment: I think the order of I²C reads is important. You need to read data from FIFO_DATA_OUT_* registers alternately: first read FIFO_DATA_OUT_L, then FIFO_DATA_OUT_H, then again FIFO_DATA_OUT_L, then FIFO_DATA_OUT_H and so on.